# Google Chrome Extension - JSON Formatting Error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm having some trouble getting the manifest for a simple Chrome extension I'm working formatted correctly.

Been going back and forth between these two pages to try to figure out the right way to write it:

https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/
https://blog.lateral.io/2016/04/create-chrome-extension-modify-websites-html-css/

```
{
  "manifest_version": 1,

  "name": "Modify HTML of a page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Adds a string into a text box",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://myawesomewebsiteURL.com/*"]
  }]

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
  "activeTab"
  ]  
}
```

Pasting the above to JSONFormatter (https://jsonformatter.org/) gives an error of

```
Parse error on line 11:
...om/*"]
  }]

  "browser_action": {
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```

Because of the error, I'm unable to load my unpacked extension into Chrome.

I understand that a compiler is looking for and end of line and sees string, but don't understand what about my syntax is keeping it from being valid.

Tried moving elements in the manifest around but can't seem to get it right.

Could someone point out what I'm missing, please?

Comment: you forgot the comma before browser_action

Comment: Thank you @PatrickEvans can't believe it was that simple!

Comment: Use an editor/IDE with a *linter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma before "browser_action".

Comment: Thanks @picciano !